# Fetch a content of file stored in an application document folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to Fetch a content of file in my application document folder. So i write a below code. But this code didn't fetch a file content in my application document folder. In my Document folder contains my needed file.

```
- (void) displayContents
{
    NSString *folderName = [@"Object File/" stringByAppendingString:strLastpath];
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName]];
    NSError *theError = nil;

    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSArray *filelist;
    int count;
    int i;

    filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:databasePath error:&theError];
    count = [filelist count];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", filelist[i]);
    }

}
```

i got the Error is:

```
2013-10-14 11:18:55.680 SampleFileCreation[1599:c07] Database Path : /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/3B43DFF3-6699-4D68-94A6-A5153F3B1404/Documents/Object File/banana.obj
2013-10-14 11:18:55.683 SampleFileCreation[1599:c07] File Exists
2013-10-14 11:18:55.685 SampleFileCreation[1599:c07] Error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Cocoa error 260** is a NSFileReadNoSuchFileError  meaning the file could not be found at the path you specified.

The problem is that your path still contains encoded spaces (%20), because you're basing it on the URL.use URL with path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    NSString *folderName = [@"Object File/" stringByAppendingString:strLastpath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[[fileManager URLsForDirectory:searchPathDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
    filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:fileURL.path error:&theError];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",textfile];

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
 NSURL *txtURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
 NSString *result= [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:txtURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Here you can get result string in result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. i fetch the contents of that file.
Using this.

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strLastpath]];
    NSError *theError = nil;

NSString *fileStering = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:databasePath encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&theError];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NSFileReadNoSuchFileError so try cleaning your project and start with a clean build if you still got the file hopefully you'll be able to read it.